# Can't find dynamically generated control, using FindName() in WPF

Tags: wpf, label, dynamically-generated, findname

I need to dynamically generate as much labels as I want, and access every single one of them when desired. but FindName() haven't been working...

Here's a simple example of what I do

I have a custom-written class, inherited from `Label` class, called myLabel.
I've put a button on my WPF project. By clicking on it, an instance of myLabel class will dynamically be created and added to the grid (myGrid) like so :

```
myLabel LBL = new myLabel();
LBL.Height = 30;
LBL.Name = "MyLabel1";
LBL.Content = "I am a label.";
myGrid.Children.Add(LBL);
```

There's another button called "Change color" which should find the previously created Label and change it's foreground color. here's the code inside that button's click event:

```
Label Thelabel = (Label)myGrid.FindName("MyLabel1");
Thelabel.Foreground = Brushes.Azure;
```

The problem is that `FindName()` never finds anything and is always null !
How can I fix that problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be issues with name scoping that are causing the 'FindName' to return null.

An explanation of a different method for finding a particular named element, starting from a parent/ancestor can be found at this post: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

give that a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Excellent! It's always good when the first thing you try works :)

Comment: Yes it's very motivating :)
Thank you again chamila_c ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the root cause of not being able to find the dynamic control is because the control was not being registered first.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername

Assuming a custom user control named `Hello`

```
Hello myHello = new Hello();
myHello.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
myHello.Name = "HelloWorld";
RegisterName("HelloWorld", myHello);

someGrid.Children.Add(myHello);
```

With `RegisterName`, you will be able to find the dynamically  generated element.